# Does the global flair include the badges gained on a meta site?

Tags: support, flair

Are badges assigned on meta sites (such as meta.english.stackexchange.com) included in the badge count shown by the global flair?

Comment: related feature-request: [Can I get Meta sites on my combined flair?](/q/288113/997587)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, per-site meta sites are not included, only this meta.stackexchange.com is included, and only the sites where you have 200+ reputation are counted for badges.

This is a copy of your flair at the moment

[image: your flair]

and you have 9 sites with 200+ reputations

- gold badges   — 10 (2+3+1+1+1+1+1)
- silver badges — 36 (8+8+5+9+1+2+1+2)
- bronze badges — 176 (38+23+16+32+20+9+13+13+12)

[image]

Comment: That answers the _how_ it is computed. I'm then interested in _why_ the badges on meta sites aren't counted.

Comment: @vonbrand because meta sites don't show "actual" achievements. which the flair exist for. :)